# How do I write a VBA code to go to a filepath, open a folder then open a file?

Tags: vba

Can anyone help me with a VBA code that goes to a folder location, opens the folder most recent folder and then opens a file. Example -

```
FileName = Book1
FolderName = Raw_Data_04.16.20 (04.16.20 is today's date)
FolderLocation = "F:\Weekly Data - Live\Archive"
```

So Filename is saved in Foldername located in FolderLocation

Comment: `FolderName = "Raw_Data_" & Format$(Date, "mm.dd.yy")`.

Comment: Are you just looking for `Workbooks.Open FolderLocation & "\" & FolderName & "\" & FileName`?

Comment: I used a combination of both your codes and it works perfectly. Thank you.